# Trying to make a circular layout with elements positioned around centre at different distances

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, mobile

I'm building a prototype android app and I'm trying to make a circular layout. Basically, I have a centre point, and I want to be able to place other elements in a circle around it, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpxUI.jpg). There's a library called ArcLayout that I tried using, and it works well, but it doesn't quite work for what I want to do. The elements I'm trying to place have a dynamic distance from the centre, and may have similar or identical distances at any given time.

I could just create a new arc layout for each distance level, but I'm trying to avoid [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7knF.jpg). Ideally, each element in the layout should position itself at a maximum distance from all other elements, while staying at the correct distance from the centre.

I've looked up a lot of different things from radar graphs, to orbiting animations, and none of them seem to work with what I want to do. How would I go about making something like this?

Comment: *I could just create a new arc layout for each distance level* - or you could look at the implementation of that library(which isn't very complex) and modify it so you could add each children with a radius value. With this you could also implement a required minimum distances between the elements.

Comment: @Luksprog unfortunately, I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this, do you have any examples?

Comment: @Luksprog minimum distances also wouldn't work because elements would have a tendency to bunch up together anyway (though they wouldn't touch, which would be a big improvement) and it could cause conflict since the number of elements is actually variable in itself. Having everything position itself at a maximum distance from everything else would ensure that the layout is spread out evenly regardless of the element's properties

Answer (score 0):

Here is a high level description of how I would do this:

Make your original view extend View class. In your ondraw method, do the following:

1. first draw the circle in the center of the view by getting the coordinate for the small circle by getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2. set some fixed radius. Store the center as cx,cy
2. Now, you need to draw other circles at the right position, for that you need the center of each circle. Now, from cx,cy if you have the angle it makes with x - axis and the distance from cx,cy to the new point, you can get the coordinates to the new points as follows:

   ```
      cx1 = cx + r*cos(theta) and cy2 = cy + r*sin(theta). 
     where r is the distance between the points and theta is the angle between line joining the points and the positive x-axis.
   ```

Just remember to convert degrees to radians in your calculations.

3. Once you get coordinates for the new circle, just draw it using canvas.drawCircle method.
4. Repeat this method as often as needed.

Comment: This would be fine if I was making a static layout, but with what I'm trying to build the distance of the elements orbiting the centre has to be dynamic, as that's an integral part of the UI. For the sake of simplicity I only drew a few circles, but the number of elements that are orbiting will also have to be dynamic. I could code some logic to randomly pull from a predefined array of angles, and have different arrays for different ranges of distances, but that seems overly complex and not nearly scalable enough.

Comment: You could change the number of circles and call invalidate unless I am missing something.

Comment: I'm just not sure how this solution would be able to place each circle at the correct angle from the centre, while being at a maximum distance from the other circles. From what I understand this only positions a circle relative to the circle at the centre.